# Three column table with different number of multiple rows

Tags: tables, multirow

I know how to use \multirow for two columns table but I can't figure out how to use it for three columns table in below picture.
[image]

Comment: multirow acts separately in each column there is nothing special about 2 columns at all, show a complete tex document that makes a start of that table and if it is giving tex errors someone will debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting it here for someone struggling with it like me. We basically start with maximum number of rows and then merge them accordingly.

```
[![\begin{table}\[ht\]
\caption{multi row table }
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \bf col 1 & \bf col 2 & \bf col 3 \\ \hline
value 1 & - & - \\
\hline
{\multirow{\9}{\*}{value 2}}&{\multirow{\3}{\*}{A}}  & C \\ 
\cline{3-3} 
        &   & D  \\
        \cline{3-3}
         &   & E \\ \cline{2-3}
         &  {\multirow{\6}{\*}{B}} & F  \\
         \cline{3-3} 
        &  & G \\
         \cline{3-3} 
        &  & H \\
         \cline{3-3} 
        &  & I \\
         \cline{3-3} 
        &  & J \\
         \cline{3-3} 
        &  & K \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{table:structure} 
\end{table}][1]][1]
```

[image: Here is how it looks]